# Updating timestamp after running make recursively

Tags: makefile

My project is dependent on other projects in subfolders. I want to call make recursively to build all in one run.

My first try is like this:

```
.PHONY: all make_recursion

all: program

program: submake1/lib submake2/lib

submake1/lib: make_recursion

submake2/lib: make_recursion

make_recursion:
    make -C submake1
    make -C submake2
```

This does not work as intended. Each run of make both submakes are executed in case a file changed in those projects. For submake2 my program is also rebuilt if submake2/lib was updated. If only submake1/lib is updated I have to run make a second time to update program.

The reason for this is that make takes the timestamp of submake1/lib before make_recursion, but does not update it after that. How can I improve this?

Comment: Why do you have a separate `make_recursion` target?

Comment: If I put the recursive make just in the rule for submakex/lib it will run if the lib file does not exists. But if a source file of the lib is updated it will not run, because lib is old. So I have to run the recursive makes each run to check if they have an updated sourcefile.

Comment: http://lcgapp.cern.ch/project/architecture/recursive_make.pdf

Comment: You can achieve the same with non-recursive make, here is the ready solution: https://github.com/igagis/prorab

Comment: Your intentions are not entirely clear, but to use Make recursively is to sacrifice much of its dependency-tracking power for the sake of simplicity. If that's what you want, we can solve *some* of these problems.